# pass post parameters from backbone to laravel

Tags: post, backbone.js, parameters, request, laravel

I am working on backend and I want to know that how I would get a post request of a parameter name file from `backbone.js`.
I want to store that parameter named `name` in my database.
Here, below are my files:

Routes:

```
Route::post('insert_document_details',array('as'=>'insert_document_details',
    'uses'=>'AuthorsController@post_document_details'));
```

Controller:

```
public function post_document_details()
{   

    // Store the original input of the request and then replace the input with your request instances input.
    $response = Request::input();

    $document_details=Response::json(Author::insert_document_details_Call($response));
    return $document_details;
}
```

Model:

```
public static function insert_document_details_Call($response)
{    
     return DB::select('call insert_document_details');
}
```

Here, `insert_document_details` is a stored procedure for inserting data in database which needs parameter `name`.

Comment: The stored procedure can be called as follows: `DB::statement(DB::raw('CALL insert_document_details('.$response['name'].');'));`.

Comment: Why you don't use `Input::get(..)` or `Input::all()` instead of `Request::input()`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Input` class in Laravel : http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input